# Is there any MSFT documentation that says RpcClientAccessServer should not be Internet-accessible?

Tags: performance, exchange-2010, outlook, dag

[This answer says](https://serverfault.com/a/524987/51457) that the RpcClientAccessServer can cause Outlook to "act slow" if it can be resolved from the Internet (assuming Outlook Anywhere is being used).

Is there any documentation that verifies this claim?

Answer (score 3):

The linked answer is most likely referring to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332317(v=exchg.141).aspx#Configuring, which states:

> It's important that the (FQDN) specified in the command be only resolvable internally. If the name is also resolvable externally, these external clients will attempt to connect to the array via a TCP connection instead of HTTPS.

This applies specifically to a Client Access Server Array, a configuration wherein multiple Client Access Servers (CAS) are load-balanced by a single public host. The back-end CASs are what should not be resolvable externally. Note that it is a best practice to implement a CAS Array, but is not required, and if you don't have one the above does not apply.

Comment: This behavior correlates to the "On [slow/fast] networks use HTTP first" options in your connection settings. If both boxes are checked, HTTP will always be used, but the default is to use RPC on fast (direct) networks, and HTTP on slow (indirect/public) networks. RPC attempts to connect directly to the RpcClientAccessServer value using RPC, and HTTP first will always connect to the RpcClientAccessServer value using your Outlook Anywhere HTTPS proxy.

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/309856-configuration-options-for-the-exchange-over-the-internet-feature-in-outlook-2010